# How to create bitmask from multiuple boolean 2D arrays and read back?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have several 2D boolean arrays and am trying to create one bitmask array (2**n) to save all of them together.

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)

mask_1 = np.random.choice(a=[False, True], size=(5,5))
mask_2 = np.random.choice(a=[False, True], size=(5,5))
mask_3 = np.random.choice(a=[False, True], size=(5,5))

mask = 2**0*mask_1 + 2**1*mask_2 + 2**2*mask_3
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct method to create the bitmask array. If this is the best method, then how to convert the `mask` to different boolean arrays?

Comment: What is your expected bit mask constructed from your 2D arrays? Could you provide a concrete example?

Comment: @liginity I want a bit mask which can be converted back to each 2D array, because each array is equal to 2**n, saving them into one bit mask could save a lot of space.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear what kind of type you want your bitmask to have. In the given example, you get an `int`. Is this what you want? If you just want a length 3 "bitmask" array with boolean type, it is better to do

```py
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)

mask = np.random.choice(a=[False, True], size=(5,5,3))

print(mask[0,0]) # [False  True False]
```

If you want the binary representation, you could use your existing method with `np.unpackbits`.

```py
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)

mask_1 = np.random.choice(a=[False, True], size=(5,5))
mask_2 = np.random.choice(a=[False, True], size=(5,5))
mask_3 = np.random.choice(a=[False, True], size=(5,5))

mask = 2**0*mask_1 + 2**1*mask_2 + 2**2*mask_3
mask = np.expand_dims(mask, axis=2)

bitmask = np.unpackbits(mask.astype(np.uint8), axis=2)
bitmask = bitmask[:,:,-3::]

print(bitmask)
# [[[0 1 0]
#  [1 1 1]...
```

But in that case, you could just generate this mask directly by randomly selecting from `a=[0,1]`...

Comment: Thanks. I want to generate a mask like the Polymer quality flags bitmask at the end of this [page](https://enmap.git-pages.gfz-potsdam.de/GFZ_Tools_EnMAP_BOX/EnPT/doc/algorithm_descriptions.html). It seems the result of `unpackbits` need to be reversed to meet the original order of mask.